# Can't get CSS gradient to fade out on transition from a:hover to a:link

Tags: css-transitions, css

and apologies if this has been addressed before. I learned a bit about fading in gradients via opacity transitions, but I'm having trouble fading them out.

I have a div that is a link, and my goal is to have a gradient fade in when the mouse is over it, and then **fade back out** when the mouse leaves the area.

Here is a link to a jsfiddle with the relevant CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/94KEZ/

This is the div itself (opacity set to 0):

```
nav .nav-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 8%;
    min-width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 8020;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.75s;
}
```

Here is the CSS for the hover (seems to be working ok…)

```
nav .nav-right:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,242,0,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,252,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00fff200', endColorstr='#ccffff00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    transition: opacity 5.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 5.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 5.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 5.75s;
}
```

I have also tried this, but it didn't seem to work:

```
nav .nav-right:link {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.75s;
}
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Or is it not possible to transition a gradient's opacity out like this?

As always, thank you for any help and advice you can offer. I am also open to suggestions of a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is posible to transition the opacity.

But to do so, the background must be constant; that is, it must be set in the base state:

CSS

```
nav .nav-right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50%;
    min-width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 8020;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%, rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,242,0,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,252,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,242,0,0) 0%,rgba(255,252,0,0) 80%,rgba(255,255,0,0.8) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00fff200', endColorstr='#ccffff00',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

nav .nav-right:link {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.75s;
}

nav .nav-right:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2.75s;
    -o-transition: opacity 2.75s;
}
```

[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/94KEZ/1/)